# Error adding custom domain name for azure website deployment slot

Tags: azure

We are trying to add a custom domain name to an existing azure website deployment slot.  The website is in Standard mode and the deployment slot has been created.  However, anytime we enter a domain name in the DNS/SSL blade and click save, we get the javascript error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of null` in `UxFxManifestScript_17328AE8.js:1962`.  Any ideas on how to resolve?  The Azure team won't help because the NEW portal is in PREVIEW, even though this functionality (deployment slots) isn't available in the OLD portal.

Comment: Deployment slots are available in the old portal.  From the list of websites, there will be a little chevron that, if clicked, will list the slots that have been created.  New slots can be created from the dashboard.

Comment: Thanks Brendan - want to post as answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the deployment slots are available via the old portal.

From the list of websites, you can expand the chevron to view existing slots:

[image]

And also, from the dashboard page, you can add new deployment slots:

[image]